# Python, user input generates turtles

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to setup a program in which the user decides how many turtles to generate and then they have a race after. My current solution is to just get an int input from the user and execute the code below (the code keeps repeating with larger numbers). I have tried putting in a loop but I am running into troubles since they all need to preform random movements in the end. Any help?

```
if turtNum >= 1:   
  turt1 = Turtle()
  turt1.color(turtColour[0])
  turt1.shape('turtle')

  turt1.penup()
  turt1.goto(0, -10)
  turt1.pendown()

  if turtNum >= 2:

    turt2Name = input('Enter a name for the second turtle: ')

    turt2 = Turtle()
    turt2.color(turtColour[1])
    turt2.shape('turtle')

    turt2.penup()
    turt2.goto(0, -25)
    turt2.pendown()
```

This is the code I tried but got this error "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

```
turtName = []
maxLengthList = turtNum
while len(turtName) < maxLengthList:
    name = input('Enter the names for the turtles: ')
    turtName.append(name)

for i in turtName:
    turtName[i] = Turtle()
    turtName[i].color(turtColour[0])
    turtName[i].shape('turtle')

    turtName[i].penup()
    turtName[i].goto(0, -10)
    turtName[i].pendown()
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: if you want to you use random position (coordinate to go to) you can use `random.random(cordinate_min ,cordinate_max)` to get random cordiante

Comment: @ChrisMueller well I'm trying to generate all of the turtles in one loop. Instead of the way my code is written out currently, I would like the user to input an integer and it would draw that amount of turtles

Comment: @user7252321 then use `input()` to get number and convert text number to `int()` - `number = int(text_with_number)` or `number = int(input(...))`

Comment: You might consider putting the calls to `.shape`, `.color`, `.penup`, `.goto`, `.pendown` in the class constructor, that would adhere better to DRY and also make this a simpler problem to solve conceptually...

Comment: @DavidZemens ok so I tried doing that but I'm clearly doing something wrong. I created a list called turtNames (which in length is equal to the user input for how many turtles they want to generate) and filled it with user inputted names. I then ran this code but I'm getting an error (list indices must be integers or slices, not str)  `for i in turtName:
    turtName[i] = Turtle()
    turtName[i].color(turtColour[0])
    turtName[i].shape('turtle')`

Comment: pls [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40976119/edit) to include additional code. Code doesn't render well in the Comments (especially multi-line code), and as such it's hard to read/understand.

Comment: @DavidZemens sorry about that. Updated the post

Comment: each `i `in `for i in turtName` is a string (assuming `turtName` is a list of string as you mentioned). you should do `for i in xrange(len(turtName))`

Answer (score 0):

You can't dangle the concept of turtle racing without expecting us to get excited about seeing it happen.  Below is a rough implementation that addresses the issues you had about entering the number of turtles, entering individual turtle information, storing it all and random motion:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from itertools import cycle
from random import randrange

MAX_TURTLES = 20
LANE_WIDTH = 25
FONT_SIZE = 18
FONT = ("Arial", FONT_SIZE, "normal")
COLORS = cycle(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan', 'black', 'yellow'])
FINISH_LINE = 350
START_LINE = -200
NAME_LINE = START_LINE - 150
DELAY = 100  # milliseconds
MAX_STEP = 10

turtles = dict()

def race():
    for name, turtle in turtles.items():  # should shuffle turtles
        turtle.forward(randrange(MAX_STEP + 1))

        if turtle.xcor() > FINISH_LINE:
            return  # the race is over

    screen.ontimer(race, DELAY)

magic_marker = Turtle(visible=False)
magic_marker.penup()

turtNum = 0

while not 1 <= turtNum <= MAX_TURTLES:
    turtNum = int(input('Enter the number of turtles: '))

for i in range(turtNum):

    name = input('Enter a name for the turtle #{}: '.format(i + 1))

    turtle = Turtle(shape="turtle")
    turtle.color(next(COLORS))

    y_offset = LANE_WIDTH * i - LANE_WIDTH * turtNum // 2

    magic_marker.color(turtle.pencolor())
    magic_marker.goto(NAME_LINE, y_offset - FONT_SIZE / 2)
    magic_marker.write(name, font=FONT)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(START_LINE, y_offset)
    turtle.pendown()

    turtles[name] = turtle

magic_marker.color('red')
magic_marker.goto(FINISH_LINE, -FINISH_LINE)
magic_marker.pendown()
magic_marker.goto(FINISH_LINE, FINISH_LINE)
magic_marker.penup()

screen = Screen()

screen.ontimer(race, DELAY)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]